# Cobra or catastrophic insurance

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, cobra

I'm about to leave a job and go on a long bikepacking trip. At the end of the trip I will be going to grad school and getting student health insurance. This is all in the United States. I have decent savings so I could cover pretty much any fee but I'd rather not. My understanding is that if something happened I could retroactively sign up for cobra for a 90 day period though it would be expensive. Alternatively I can get catastrophic health insurance to cover anything that might happen. The way I see it I can avoid paying any premiums if I take the cobra option but it may be costly to activate it if anything happens. If I get the catastrophic coverage I will have to pay some premiums but will be covered in a worse case scenario.

I am an otherwise young healthy individual who requires no regular medication or treatment.

Are there other things I should consider?

Comment: Define a long trip? would you be on the trip when the deadlines happen? Also how will they get the COBRA paperwork to you if you leave before it arrives? What coverage will you have with COBRA if the trip is several states away?

Comment: *"worse case scenario"*: Earth is destroyed to make way for an interstellar bypass?

Comment: 60 days for long trip. Will have them shipped to an address I have someone who can check the mail at. @mhoran_psprep

Comment: We've got to have bypasses